# How is ${n \choose n/2}$ approximated in this manner?

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813440/the-asymptotic-growth-of-n-choose-floorn-2), the author asked how to get an asymptotic growth of ${n \choose n/2}$, to which the answer is as follows. First:

$$ {n \choose n/2} = \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n- n/2)!} = \frac{n!}{(\tfrac{n}{2}!)^2} $$

Now, to find an upper bound on this, take the upper bound of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $n!$ and the lower bound for $\tfrac{n}{2}!$ which if I'm not mistaking gives the following:

$$ {n \choose n/2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n e^{\tfrac{1}{12n}}}{\Big( \sqrt{2 \pi \tfrac{n}{2}} (\frac{\tfrac{n}{2}}{e})^\tfrac{n}{2} e^{\tfrac{1}{12\tfrac{n}{2}+1}}\Big )^2} $$

However, the answer states this should give:

$$ {n \choose n/2} \leq \frac{e \cdot n^{n + \tfrac{1}{2}} e^{-n}}{\Big( \sqrt{2 \pi} \cdot \tfrac{n}{2}^\tfrac{n+1}{2} e^{-\tfrac{n}{2}}\Big )^2} $$

I'm confused as to how one would get from the former to the latter. Up to now I get stuck around here:

$$ {n \choose n/2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n e^{\tfrac{1}{12n}}}
{\Big( \sqrt{2 \pi \tfrac{n}{2}} (\frac{\tfrac{n}{2}}{e})^\tfrac{n}{2} e^{\tfrac{1}{12\tfrac{n}{2}+1}}\Big )^2} \\
\leq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n} \cdot n^n e^{-n} e^{\tfrac{1}{12n}}}
{\Big( \sqrt{2 \pi \tfrac{n}{2}} \cdot \tfrac{n}{2}^\tfrac{n}{2} e^{-\tfrac{n}{2}} e^{\tfrac{1}{12\tfrac{n}{2}+1}}\Big )^2} \\
\leq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi} \cdot n^{n + \tfrac{1}{2}} e^{-n} e^{\tfrac{1}{12n}}}
{\Big( \sqrt{2 \pi} \cdot \tfrac{n}{2}^\tfrac{n+1}{2} e^{-\tfrac{n}{2}} e^{\tfrac{1}{12\tfrac{n}{2}+1}}\Big )^2}
$$

Now, do the latter terms just disappear due to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{\tfrac{1}{12n}}}{\Big ( e^{\tfrac{1}{12\tfrac{n}{2}+1}}\Big )^2} = 0$? But in this case, why should there still be an $e$ term in the numerator? Also what happened to the $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ in the numerator? It cannot have canceled out with the one in the denominator since the latter is still there...

Comment: As a rule, use $n/2$ rather than $\frac n2$ in exponents an numerators - it becomes a lot less messy.

Comment: The latter terms disappear because that limit is $1,$ not zero. That's because the numerator and denominator both go to $1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews will do, wasn't sure which to use, both seemed messy.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That solves the latter terms indeed, I suppose all I'm missing now is the $e$ term popping in the numerator.

Comment: Yeah, these expressions are a mess no matter what. And \left and \right on the parentheses seems to end up very wrong.

Comment: It appears that answer is using the looser bound $\sqrt{2\pi} < n!e^n/n^{n+1/2}\le e$ given later in the article. Your bounds give the significantly tighter coefficient $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ instead of $e/\pi$ on $2^n/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Also, check out the Central Binomial Coefficient at wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It seems the answerer didn't use the inequality chain stated in the *[Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)*
as starting point, but started instead with the *[asymptotic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation*)*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{n!\sim\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain from (1) assuming even $n$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}&\sim\left(\frac{n/2}{e}\right)^{n/2}\sqrt{\pi n}=\left(\frac{n}{2e}\right)^{n/2}\sqrt{\pi n}\\
&=\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}e^{-n/2}\sqrt{\pi n}=\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}e^{-n/2}\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\\
&\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n/2}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
and squaring (2) gives the denominator of the expression under consideration
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{n/2}\stackrel{?}{\leq}\frac{e\,n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n/2}\right)^2}
\end{align*}

From (1) and (2) we derive the asymptotic formula
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{n}{n/2}}&\sim\frac{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{-n/2}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\,n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,e^{-n}}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{-n/2}\right)^2}\tag{$ \sqrt{2\pi}\leq e$}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{\leq \frac{e\,n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,e^{-n}}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{-n/2}\right)^2}}
\end{align*}
where the last inequality holds only if $n$ is *sufficiently* large.

Answer (score 2):

Using,as you did,

$$\sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n + 1}} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n}}$$
$$\frac{2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{1}{12 n+1}-\frac{1}{3 n}}}{\sqrt{\pi n}
  }\lt \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} \lt \frac{2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{2}{6 n+1}}}{\sqrt{\pi n} }$$
You could use
$$e^{\frac{1}{12 n+1}-\frac{1}{3 n}}=1-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{7}{288 n^2}-\frac{1}{3456 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{2}{6 n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{25}{288 n^2}-\frac{89}{3456
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which give very tight bounds.

For $n=10$, this gives
$$ 251.972 < 252 < 252.127 $$

**Edit**

I use the opportunity of the post to put an unpublised result from one of my past students, the late Dr. Bois,
$$\color{blue}{\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} > \frac{2^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\, e^{-\frac 1 {4n}}}{\sqrt{\pi n} }}$$ which is, for any $n$, better than the above left bound. For $n=10$, it gives $251.990$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a general hint, too long for comment: it's good to practice, but a math software like Maxima is free and it helps a lot when things get messy - at least to check results. In this case, to get the upper bound

```
   stU(n) := sqrt(2*%pi*n) * (n/%e)^n * exp(1/(12*n)); /*  stirling approx, upper bound */

   stL(n) := sqrt(2*%pi*n) * (n/%e)^n * exp(1/(12*n+1)); /*  stirling approx, lower bound */

   cfU(n) := stU(n) /( stL(n/2)^2);

   factor(cfU(n))
```

outputs

$$\frac{{{2}^{n+\frac{1}{2}}} {{e}^{\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{2}{6 n+1}}}}{\sqrt{{n\pi} }} $$

Of course, the exponential tends to one. IF you want to refine that:

```
taylor( ev( %e^(1/(12*n)-2/(6*n+1)) , n = 1/x) , x , 0 , 4);
```

outputs

$$1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{25 {{x}^{2}}}{288}-\frac{89 {{x}^{3}}}{3456}+\frac{1211 {{x}^{4}}}{165888}$$